# Limit evaluate $ \lim\limits_{x \to - \infty } {{|\arcsin ({2 \over x})|} \over {\arctan ({5 \over x})}} $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

Please help me with this limit without using L'Hôpital's rule. I would by happy if you use simple solving. Thank you as much as I can ;).

$ \lim\limits_{x \to - \infty } {{|\arcsin ({2 \over x})|} \over {\arctan ({5 \over x})}} $

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1513566), and not in a good way. The sooner you change your approach to this site, the better your experience here will be.

Comment: I do not know how to start to solve this limit, because I never seen something like that

Comment: @NormalHuman I had already flagged, asked my officemate to flag.

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi Thanks; it has some close votes now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{\arcsin(u)}{\arctan(v)}=\frac{\arcsin(u)}{u}\cdot \frac{u}{v}\cdot \frac{v}{\arctan(v)}.$$
Therefore, if $u(x),v(x)\underset{x\to a}{\longrightarrow} 0$, $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\arcsin(u(x))}{\arctan(v(x))}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know are

(1) $|x| > 0$ if $x \ne 0$.

(2) $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}
= 1$
for all the functions
and their inverses
mentioned in this problem.